# PhpMyAdmin - table does not contain a unique column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i'm using XAMPP and there while i try to edit a product by double clicking the row, it gives me error: `This table does not contain a unique column. Features related to the grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete links may not work after saving.`

I do have a unique autoincrement column in my table though, here is my table schema (from a sql dump):

```
CREATE TABLE `productAttributes` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `productId` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `attributeValueId1` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attributeValueId2` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `characteristics_en` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `productAttributes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`),
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `productAttributes`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

So why it gives this error even if my table has unique column ?

Comment: What is the query used in phpMyAdmin where you see this message? If it doesn't include the column __id__, or you use a group by, you'll see that message.

Comment: i Simply double click in the characteristics_en to enter something. On focus out it tries to save and produces that error.

Comment: Just in case anyone had the same prob, it was a bug of phpMyAdmin. Updated to latest version and worked.

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis please state which version had the bug and to which one you upgraded.

Comment: @MarcDelisle Upgraded from 4.5.6 to 4.7.1 which is the latest by the time speaking